# JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'addEventListener

Tags: javascript, jquery

Am using Asp.Net 2.0, am trying drag and drop files using asp.net.
for this process am using following js's

```
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/modernizr-2.5.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

that's why the error comes like this

```
JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'addEventListener
```

am using IE11

so i was used one code

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge;" />
```

it is not working

and my script is

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">



    var selectedFiles;

      $(document).ready(function () {
alert("");
        if (!Modernizr.draganddrop) {
        //alert("2");
          alert("This browser doesn't support File API and Drag & Drop features of HTML5!");
          return;
        }

        var box;
        box = document.getElementById("box");
       alert(box);
        box.addEventListener("dragenter", OnDragEnter, false);
        box.addEventListener("dragover", OnDragOver, false);
        box.addEventListener("drop", OnDrop, false);

        $("#upload").click(function () {
          var data = new FormData();
          for (var i = 0; i < selectedFiles.length; i++) {
            data.append(selectedFiles[i].name, selectedFiles[i]);
          }
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "FileHandler.ashx",
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: data,
            success: function (result) {
              alert(result);
            },
            error: function () {
              alert("There was error uploading files!");
            }
          });
        });

      });;

      function OnDragEnter(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
      }

      function OnDragOver(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
      }

      function OnDrop(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        selectedFiles = e.dataTransfer.files;
        $("#box").text(selectedFiles.length + " file(s) selected for uploading!");
      }



    </script>
```

and my aspx page is

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<center>
  <div id="box">Drag & Drop files from your machine on this box.</div>
  <br />
  <input id="upload" type="button" value="Upload Selected Files" />
</center>
</form>
```

But this application drag and drop files is working fine in chrome and firefox
only problem in IE

Suggest me to get a solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the object being returned for box (box = document.getElementById("box");)? Is it a div?

Answer (score 0):

take out ie11 from your met tag, and instead add the following code. This is explained [here](http://www.markadrake.com/blog/2013/12/13/sharepoint-workflows-fail-using-ie11/).

```
/* IE11 Fix for SP2010 */
if (typeof UserAgentInfo.strBrowser !== 'undefined' && !window.addEventListener) {
     UserAgentInfo.strBrowser=1;
}
```

Comment: Why you think the question has anything to do with Sharepoint?

Answer (score 0):

What's your document mode set to in IE?

Press F12 and you should see a dropdown with a number or the word edge, make sure it's set to edge. Even though you're using the meta tag to set the document mode if you previously had it set to anything else it will override that.

Comment: yes, if i set edge no error comes , but other are design collide and the drag and drop is not working .

Answer (score 0):

Edit the plunkr to see where it fails - I don't have jQuery 1.7.2 to hand...but tested in internet explorer 11 and can't see that error. I'm using the click event as it is an easier event to generate in the browser and it is the addEventListener method that is throwing.

http://embed.plnkr.co/Smm421v5In2YYJAJXNTW/preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge;" />
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.0.0-rc2" data-semver="3.0.0-rc2" rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0-rc2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="jquery" data-semver="2.0.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="bootstrap@3.0.0-rc2" data-semver="3.0.0-rc2" src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0-rc2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <div id="box" style="height: 100px; background-color: red">Click area</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

...and in the script...

```
'use strict';
/* global $ */


console.log("Hey!");
$(document).ready(function() {
  var box;
  box = document.getElementById("box");
  console.log(box);
  box.addEventListener("click", OnClick, false);
});    

var OnClick = function() {
  console.log('in OnClick');
  $("#box").text("Clicked");
};
```

Answer (score -1):

This is due to compatibility issue add below in the web.config file

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=EmulateIE9" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```